# UILabel frame changes after rotation

Tags: iphone, uikit, uilabel, cgaffinetransform

In my application i am rotating a `UILabel` using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`. I need to save the rotation angle and frame of `UILabel` and then recreate that label with same position and angle. But after rotation, the frame of `UILabel` gets changed and saving that frame and recreate the label with that frame and angle not giving me the exact position, where it was previously placed. Can any one help out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The frame property does only contain usable information in case of an identity transformation. Otherwise it is undefined and should be ignored.
If you want to display a rotated `UILabel`, just apply the transformation. You don't need to worry about the frame. The size of the label will remain the same, just as if it wasn't transformed.

Set the frame, then rotate. Done.